# How do I use Vue.js v-for to iterate over a Number variable?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

For example, say I have a positive integer variable, `rating`.

The documentation http://vuejs.org/guide/list.html#Range-v-for only lists using Number directly, however switching the number out for a variable doesn't work as expected.

I currently am doing this:

`<i v-for="i in rating" class="fa fa-2x fa-star">{{ rating }}</i>`

but unfortunately it's only showing once, even through ratings value is `4`. Am I missing anything in the documentation?

Comment: Can you post a jsfiddle of what you are seeing? This seems to work as expected. https://jsfiddle.net/okv0rgrk/5665/

Comment: You're right it does, I put it together in a webpackbin and it seems to be fine. http://www.webpackbin.com/4yoYt4Ju-

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out what the issue was, I am passing the rating value in via property, so it was being passed in as a string. See non-working example here:

```
<rating-component value="rating"></rating-component>
```

vs

```
<rating-component :value="rating"></rating-component>
```

By switching out `value` property to `:value`, to use the literal variable instead of the string variable it fixed my issue.

Comment: I don't remember exactly what the code was, but I'll remove the link and add  what would make sense.

Comment: is it possible to cast a string type to int, after data has been passed the html view??

Comment: You could use `parseInt()` if you absolutely had to.